# PHP + MySQL + Ajax Search or Data Framework

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i tried several ajax/js "frameworks" and "data grids" to show some mysql data, but the problem is that i have to many columns (like 50) and some of then need to be links, images and also get the ID from the same query to create those links

the main features that im looking is good search, sort and filter

i dont have the time to make all of this script (and learn more about ajax), i'm not a php/mysql beginner but the problem is the ajax thing. so what im looking for is some script, framework, datagrid or anything that could make what i described, with less code edit as possible

if you can came up with another solution that already comes with ajax, that might be useful too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to try out [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).  Besides the jQuery version, they have a new all-PHP version that handles all the programming without AJAX.  It might be exactly what you're looking for.  It handles large data sets, and has a huge demo site with example code, including the PHP/MySQL back end.

Comment: best. grid. ever.
thank you, im going to adapt the code and see if i can get the images and ID's working